# Regular expression to identify a function whose general type is <FUNCTION NAME>#(arg1,[arg2],[agr3]....)

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

Consider the below

**Case 1:**  `SDN#(X,)`

**Case 2:** `SDN#(X,12)`

**Case 3:** `SDN#(34,12)`

**Case 4:** `CORR#(X,,)`

**Case 5:** `CORR#(X,12,45)`

**Case 6:** `CFH#(X,AVG)`

These all are some kind of custom functions.

How can I build a regular expression that will identity that the given text satisfies the function requirement

The generalised structure is as **<FUNCTION NAME>#(arg1,[arg2],[agr3]....)**

e.g. *given CORR, or CORR#() it is not a funciton.*

**Because every function must have atleast one argument(which will be alphanumeric).**

My approach so far is

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"([A-Z]+)[#]([A-Z a-z 0-9]+),([A-Z a-z 0-9]+),([A-Z a-z 0-9]+)");
Match m = r.Match(txtFunction.Text);
if (m.Success) MessageBox.Show("OK");
else MessageBox.Show("Not OK");
```

But it is not working

I am using C#3.0

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't you have to escape the `(` and `)` somehow in order to detect them as *text* and not using them as group indicators?

Comment: Works fine but also picks up CORR#() which is not the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt (even if I don't know if its working in C#):

```
[A-Z]+#\(([A-Za-z0-9]+,?)*,*\)
```

Explanation: using `CORR#(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

`[A-Z]+#` matches the function name, here `CORR#`

`\(` matches the opening parentheses `(`. Note that I escaped the `(` in order to tell the engine not to take it as a grouping construct.

`([A-Za-z0-0]+,?)*` matches `arg1, arg2,`. Note that it's a bit hacky because of the `,?` which indicates that there might be a `,` at the end, but it is not necessary.

`,*` matches "empty commata".

`\)` matches the closing parentheses. Note that I escaped the `)` in order to tell the engine not to take it as a grouping construct.

Comment: I have done Regex r = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+#\(([A-Za-z0-0]+,)*[A-Za-z0-9]+\)");.. But it is matching only case 2 & 6

Answer (score 0):

If you have meaningless spaces in your regex (like you have), you have to specify `IgnorePatternWhitespace` for the `RegexOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specificaly C# regex flavor, but this one works in PCRE for all your cases :

```
/^[A-Z]+#\(([a-zA-Z0-9]*,?)*\)$/
```